# RSS Feed cURL error 52?

Tags: rss, feed

Has anyone every encountered this error when trying to publish a feed onto another site?

The feed appears fine say within Reeder or a browser, but when it comes to showing it on another site it fails.

I've tried turning off all the plugins.
Re-uploading all the core WordPress files.

Neither have any effect, the site is run on PHP7 and i'm stuck on what to do next.

```
object(WP_Error)#5664 (2)  {
    ["errors"]=> array(1) {
        ["simplepie-error"]=> array(1) {
            [0]=> string(53) "WP HTTP Error: cURL error 52: Empty reply from server"
        }
    } 
    ["error_data"]=> array(0) { }
}
```

The code i'm using to pull in the feed which i think is okay..

```
<?php 

if ( ! function_exists( 'fetch_feed' ) ) {
    include_once( trailingslashit( ABSPATH . WPINC ) . 'feed.php' ); // include the required file
}

$feed = fetch_feed( 'http://pageonemedia.co.uk/feed/rss/' );// specify the source feed

if ( ! is_wp_error( $feed ) ) :

    $limit = $feed->get_item_quantity( 1 );// specify number of items
    $items = $feed->get_items( 0, $limit );

    if ( 0 == $limit || ! $items ) : ?>

        <div>The feed is either empty or unavailable.</div>

    <?php else :

        foreach ( $items as $item ) : ?>

            <h3 class="section_title sub [ blue medium_spacing ]"><?php echo $item->get_title(); ?></h3>


        <?php endforeach;

    endif;

endif; ?>
```

Comment: You don't have a feed on `http://pageonemedia.co.uk/feed/rss/`.

Comment: Sorry  it should be... http://pageonemedia.co.uk/feed/